# How to Split a Layout into two equal rows?

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-layout

This is the code written in main Layout

```
 <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            >

    </LinearLayout>
```

I need two linear layouts inside this parent layout such that the parent layout gets split into two halves..

Comment: Use weight property of the linear layout.

Answer (score 6):

Use this code

```
 <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1">

                //Other Stuff

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1">

                //Other Stuff

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:weightSum="2"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:background="@android:color/black"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <!--child 1-->

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <!--child 2-->

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

we have use layout_weight to create these type of layout.
try this code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <!--First Row-->
    <LinearLayout
        android:background="@android:color/black"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight=".5">



    </LinearLayout>
<!--Second Row-->
    <LinearLayout
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight=".5">



    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```